# How to get an independent review of my article?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, papers

I am writing my first paper on Machine Learning. I worked on a problem, took the results, and wrote the paper. I discussed the results with my teachers and seniors; they said it looked fine.

Now I want to write a paper, and I wrote it following other papers. But I wanted to get it checked independently by an expert.

I thought to discuss the issue here. May I post this here, or in any open room forum? Or do you have any other suggestions? I do not want to post to the board of editors in journal as they do not review very sharp makes very gross comment.

Comment: Some overlap with http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/using-cross-validated-for-a-pre-review-of-an-idea-that-might-be-suited-for-a-p?rq=1 Two possibilities, I think. Use chat to ask for a volunteer (to be candid, low probability of getting one, I would guess). Post your novel idea as a question you answer yourself to get comments on it. Otherwise, it's hard to see that this would fit in here.

Comment: Thank you for some suggestions. The concepts are clear. They are standard text book things. The issue is the way I am arranging data and results in paper I am on cross thought whether they are fine. I generally crossed with papers on similar problems looks fine, but looking once for an expert help.

Answer (score 8):

> I thought to discuss the issue here. May I post this here, or in any open room forum?

I don't think so, because Stack Exchange is designed for Q/A format. Therefore, discussing a whole study/paper would be off-topic. If there is a particular issue you want to discuss, it would be necessary to adapt it to a answerable question.

> Or do you have any other suggestions?

Yes. Submit the article.

It seems you were already suitably cautious for someone who is writing the first paper:

1. You discussed method/results with your advisors who said they were OK.
2. You already set the structure of your article's text according to other published materials (as long as the papers used as examples are good examples, this is positive).

The peer review will address some issues you may have overlooked and there will be a chance for you to improve it. Moreover, it is very unlikely that a first paper will be approved without needing at least one review. I wish you good luck on this task.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you for giving necessary courage. Yes, if there is some point I can discuss with you and my teachers.

Comment: +1, I didn't respond to this question because I wasn't sure how to address it. This is the right approach & good advice for the OP as well.